# Alternative way to mark a noexcept function as not implemented

Tags: c++, exception

I like to do this if I have only written an empty or partial implementation of a function:

```
... foo(...)
{
    // Some unfinished implementation or empty

    throw std::runtime_error("Not implemented.");
}
```

, so that I won't forget to complete the implementation before using it . And the code can compile and will work fine so long as I don't use it.

However, this will cause the compiler to give either a warning or an error if `foo()` has `noexcept`. Is there an alternative yet *elegant* way to achieve this?

Comment: `std::terminate` ?

Comment: I really would start by writing failing unit tests. 
You can also add an "assert(false)" (debug builds only)

Comment: @PepijnKramer I like the idea of writing failing unit tests. As for `assert(false)`, `assert()` is not marked as `noexcept` in en.cppreference.

Comment: Oh yes, using assert then might be a bit of an issue or you need to wrap it in an noexcept function (with try/catch(...))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always terminate the program:

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>

[[noreturn]] void Unimplemented(
    std::source_location caller,
    std::source_location called = std::source_location::current()) noexcept {
    std::cerr << "Unimplemented function\n"
              << called.file_name() << '(' << called.line()
              << "): " << called.function_name() << "\ncalled from\n"
              << caller.file_name() << '(' << caller.line()
              << "): " << caller.function_name() << '\n';
    std::terminate();
}

void foo(std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) noexcept {
    Unimplemented(loc);
}

int main() {
    foo(); 
}
```

Possible output:

```
Unimplemented function
/app/example.cpp(15): void foo(std::source_location)
called from
/app/example.cpp(19): int main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. It is nearly perfect, but still less traceable than an exception. Debuggers usually break on an exception so I can identify where I called the function with the call stack. I upvoted your answer, and will accept it if I have not seen a better one.

Comment: @GuanyumingHe I added an idea for making it more traceable.

Comment: Both `std::cerr::operator<<` and file I/O are not `noexcept`. So logging also has its flaws. I think I can use something like `__debugbreak()` in MSVC, but that's compiler-specific. I know logging normally won't throw but it is not `noexcept`, as file I/O or other I/O are involved.

Comment: @GuanyumingHe Your logging should always be `noexcept`. Just add a `try` ... `catch` around the logging part in `Terminate` (if your logger isn't already `noexcept`) in the `Terminate` function and `Terminate` will then be 100% `noexcept`

Comment: Oh I realized I could do that. Thank you. I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @GuanyumingHe debuggers normally break on terminate? Which debugger are you using that doesn't?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I haven't tried. I think `std::terminate()` is like `exit()`, for which a debugger doesn't break.

Comment: @GuanyumingHe, no by default `std::terminate` calls `std::abort` which is normally caught by debuggers